# Plugin is not showing up in openfire console

Tags: java, plugins, ant, openfire

I've followed this tutorial http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html and made a simple plugin that is basically a broadcast plugin found in wildfire source, but also uses google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar and java-json-schema.jar.

After I've built my plugin with ant tool like this

```
ant -buildfile <path to build.xml in wildfire source> plugin -Dplugin=_HelloWorld -lib <path to translate and json jars>
```

and got one warning among other text that seemed ok

```
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
```

i've uploaded it to openfire server.

The problem is, my plugin never shows up in the list of plugins in openfire console.
Can this be related to a java version this google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar uses? I am using java 1.7.0_71.

I should mention that google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar and java-json-schema.jar do work in eclipse where I've set java 1.7.0_71.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the include section. Copy/paste from BroadcastPlugin.java solved it.